# how to setup daemons on a machine with multiple IPs?

Tags: networking, web-server

I have a linux box with two IP addresses (say IP1, and IP2).

I have a server-process listening to a specific port (say 60000). Now, I want to run two copies of the server-process on the above linux box. How can I set up my system such that I can have process1 handle packets to IP1:60000 and have process2 handle packets to IP2:60000?

Or can I?

Answer (score 4):

Generally most daemons will have an option in the config to control which IP address and Port pair it will **bind** or listen on (see `man 2 bind` for the nitty-gritty C system call level details).

After you have changed the configuration and restarted the daemon, you can see what it is bound to using the `netstat -ln` command. Example output will be something like:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

`0.0.0.0` means all IPs and the `:22` means it is listening destination TCP port 22. The second column `0.0.0.0:*` means accepts all source IPs and source ports.

In your case you should see one row that has a local address like `12.12.12.12:6000` and another row with a local address like `13.13.13.13:6000`.

If you there doesn't seem to be an option in the configuration file, it might be a command line switch for the daemon itself. In that case you might need to edit the start up file in `/etc/init.d/whatever`. This is usually not the case however.

Comment: But the process will still have the port bound on both IPs, and the second instance won't be able to bind the same port.

Comment: @mfinni: Oh didn't read that quite right. Ya, iptables won't help.

Answer (score 0):

The process itself is generally in control of the IP addresses it listens on. For example, in Apache, you set up the listening IP in the `<VirtualHosts>` directive.